# Add item to main menu (nav-main-author) in CP

Tags: control-panel

Using Expressionengine 3.5.11

I would like to add another item alongside:

- 'Create'
- 'Edit'
- 'Files'
- 'Members'

in the Admin control panel for for creating Pages.

I found instructions for adding a custom dropdown menu but that's not what I want. According to Ellis Labs docs Pages should have been added to the Create menu when I installed it, but it wasn't.

Will I have to do this by hacking the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a link to that pages. Go in *Setting -> Menu Manager -> Manage* (a menu set of you choice) and *Add Menu Item -> Single Link ->* https://yourdomaine/yoursystemfolder/index.php?/cp/addons/settings/pages OR directly the channel where you want to create the page.
The new item menu will appear below the main menu.

Comment: Almost what I needed, there was a 'Default' menu that I had to add things to.